# insertBefore pushes elements down

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to insert a div above another div with insertBefore and so far it is working like it should.  However, it pushes down the div I am trying to insert it above and I would like to prevent that if possible.  Here is the code I am using along with a jsFiddle example:

JS:

```
var innerDiv = document.getElementById('innerDiv');

function addButtons() {
    var buttons = document.createElement('div'),
        outerDiv = document.getElementById('outerDiv');

    buttons.innerHTML = '<input type="button" id="button" value="button" />';  

    outerDiv.insertBefore(buttons, outerDiv.childNodes[0]);        
}

innerDiv.onfocus = addButtons;​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="outerDiv" class="outerDiv">
     <div id="innerDiv" contenteditable="true">Testing</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outerDiv {
    position: fixed;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
}​
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qGZeK/1/)

Thankyou for your help

Comment: problem is you are adding to the container that contains the innerDiv so the pushing down is expected. Give the button a negative margin (height: Npx; margin-top: -Npx) or rethink how you are doing this.

Comment: Do U only want to add one element or number of elements above the ID ?

Comment: I only want to add one element above the ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal. Since the `outerDiv` has fixed positioning, it will keep its current position on the screen, but its content will be flowed according to the normal layout algorithm. You're inserting the `button` before the `innerDiv`, so the button will be the new first child inside `outerDiv`, so it will take the position right at the start of `outerDiv`. (You do know that `insertBefore` inserts **inside** the element on which you're calling the method, **before** the child element that you specify as the second argument, right?)

If you want the new element not to influence the layout, you should add some style to it. [For example](http://jsfiddle.net/qGZeK/2/):

```
#button {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2em;
}
```

Comment: I figured it was normal, just wasn't sure how to workaround it. that works, thankyou

Comment: how would it affect responsiveness?

Comment: @ameyarote I agree, this was just an example of how it can be done with CSS. A good solution will depend on the actual usecase, UI, etc. There's no generic solution for such a broad issue, and other solutions could include floats inside margins, working with `visibility` instead of adding new elements, changing paddings on `outerDiv` when adding the new element, and many many others.

Comment: @SergiuDumitriu - U r partly right with CSS part and actual USECASE, UI. But there has to be some generic sol. With respect to this query OP wants only one ID to be added ,which limits the scope of work.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the innerDiv absolute Positioned: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qGZeK/3/)**

```
.innerDiv{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}

.outerDiv {
    position: fixed;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: that inserts the button below the div, which is not what I was looking for.

Comment: If you dont want to have padding, remove the padding-top attribute from outerDiv class

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this is one of the best way which will keep the page responsive as well as fulfill to add element above the id.

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qGZeK/4/)

I have made some changes in CSS

```
.outerDiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    left: 100px;
}    

#innerDiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
}
```

Where `.outerdiv` is taken up and `#innerdiv` is placed just below the `.outerdiv`. It seems like we are adding an element above the ID , which is what required.

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize what you were asking at first, what I really want to do is add a button below the div also, which then throws this method off a little bit

Comment: U want button above and below the id, correct? and how many such buttons u require ? or only one button above and below is required

Comment: there will be three to five buttons below, but they will all be in the same row.

Comment: That's what @akhilesh has done smartly. please be specific what exactly uwant and give sample example(diagram will be nice) to help U.

Comment: what he does adds the button that is supposed to be on the top, to the bottom. Your example works perfectly if I just want to add a button to the top, however, when I am adding a button to the bottom the, bottom button appears behind the div

Comment: Sorry ,Your explanation is not useful for what exactly u want.